# What are good Tor resources?

Tags: anonymity, configuration, onion-routing

There is some documentation at Tor projects on how to use Tor such as https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en#warning **However, if one would like to be very good at using Tor/Anonymity techniques then what would be the best online resources to learn how to use Tor well?** (please suggest good links) What I am looking for is not just a click and go guide but something with a little more depth. For some people the proper use of Tor may be life or death and proper use would be essential. (If I hand Tor to a friend in Iran then how can he be comfortable just clicking and going? He would want documentation to KNOW that how he was going online was close to a best possible method.)

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that there is not a single document but a collection of links that properly answers this. I will try to put together a small guide with links as an answer to my own question within a few weeks if there is no other thorough answer. This has taken me a bit of time to research.

Answer (score 1):

Getting a in depth guide is good, but they can never cover everything. It is important to learn the thought processes of computer security and anonymity(knowing when to use a new identity is a basic example of this). I suggest finding text in relation to that as well.

You said you found some documentation on the Tor website - there is probably a lot more if you dig for it, there is also probably a wiki somewhere on the subject (no, not the Hidden Wiki).

Comment: Yes. In fact I found some "other" information that I didn't see before. I also found links to other information at the TOR website. I plan to try to put it together in a document and poost it here. It will take me some work to do that. I didn't bookmark everything I looked at and will have to find some of it again.